# Como fazer para usar if dentro do for, sem que o if de fora apareça?

Tags: c, if, for, else

```
printf("\nDigite o usuario que deseja pesquisa, pela Matricula: \n");
gets(strL);
busca=atoi(strL);
for(i=0; i<quant; i++) {
    if(busca==dados[i].matricula) {
        printf("Aluno: %d\n",i);
        printf("Nome: %s\n",dados[i].nome);
        printf("CPF: %s\n",dados[i].cpf);
        printf("Matricula: %d\n",dados[i].matricula);
        printf("Idade: %d\n",dados[i].idade);
        printf("\n-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-\n");
    }
}
    if(busca!=dados[i].matricula) {
       printf("pesquisa invalida, tente novamente! \n");
    }
```

O código compilar normalmente. O problema é que o primeiro `if` é para quando for igual e o segundo é para quando `for` diferente e nesse caso, quando eu compilo tanto o `if` dentro do for quanto o fora do `for`, e executado, sendo que só um é verdadeiro.

[image: printf("pesquisa invalidade invalidade, tente novamente");]

Comment: Note que quando encerrar o loop `for` o valor da variável `i` será `quant` e portanto a condição do if após o loop será, quase com toda certeza, falso, até porque você está acessando uma posição fora dos limites do array. Ligue alguma flag caso você encontre ou encerre o loop ao encontrar (talvez neste caso um while seja melhor).

Comment: Outra possibilidade é você colocar um `break;` ao final do if interno ao loop, ou seja sair do loop quando encontrar mas, mesmo nesse caso, o melhor é verificar se `i >= quant` para informar que não encontrou.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma é usando uma função já que sem ela teria que criar uma *flag* que é gambiarra, e a função isola melhor o que é cada coisa.

Você quer que mostre o usuário se achar e depois encerre isso sem mais nada, ou então se ele pesquisou todos os usuários e não achou um dado quer que uma mensagem indique isso, portanto:

```
void mostraUsuario(int codigo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++) {
        if (dados[i].matricula == codigo) {
            printf("Aluno: %d\n",i);
            printf("Nome: %s\n",dados[i].nome);
            printf("CPF: %s\n",dados[i].cpf);
            printf("Matricula: %d\n",dados[i].matricula);
            printf("Idade: %d\n",dados[i].idade);
            printf("\n-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-\n");
            return;
        }
        printf("pesquisa invalida, tente novamente! \n");
        return;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/NotFound.c).

Tem outros problemas no código, mesmo sem ver todo ele, mas funcionará em um exercício, por isso não vou tentar resolver.